# Does openssl always encrypt the private key?

Tags: linux, openssl, private-key

When using openssl 0.9.8 to create a new self-signed cert+key, there is a `-nodes` parameter that can be used to tell openssl to not encrypt the private key it creates.  For example:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 \
    -subj '/C=US/ST=Florida/L=Jupiter/CN=test.com' \
    -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout mykey.pem -out mycert.pem
```

But with the new openssl v1.0.1, it seems as if the `-nodes` parameter is ignored.  From what I can tell, the private key is always encrypted.  Am I using openssl wrong?  Is there a different parameter I should be using instead?

The `-nodes` parameter is documented to mean:

```
if this option is specified then if a private
key is created it will not be encrypted
```

Source: http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/req.html#item__nodes

---

More details as asked:

With openssl 0.9.8, the key + cert can be directly imported into other 3rd-party devices we have which expect un-encrypted keys and certs.  This works without any problem.

But when using openssl 1.0.1, these 3rd-party devices complain the key is invalid.  The exact error message is:

```
ERROR: Private key for 'My Cert' does not appear to be a valid
RSA private key in PEM format.
```

This is a closed source system, and it doesn't provide additional details.  What I've discovered through playing around with it today is if I run the v1.0.1 private key through this command:

```
openssl rsa -in mykey.pem -out decryptedkey.pem
```

...then at that point this 3rd party system has no problem importing the cert and the decrypted key.  And when I run this command on the v1.0.1 key:

```
 openssl rsa -text -in mykey.pem
```

...the text of the private key is not the same as what is in the v1.0.1 mykey.pem file.  This is why I thought the key was somehow encrypted.

Comment: (For now, as a workaround, I have to run this additional command to decrypt the key after it is created:  `openssl rsa -in mykey.pem`.  But I'd rather find the right way to get `openssl req` to work as documented.)

Comment: Works for me with 1.0.1 on Ubuntu Precise.

Comment: The command works fine.  The problem is the key is encrypted.  The way you can tell is run it through "openssl rsa -in mykey.pem".  If the input and output are not the same, then it means it was encrypted.

Comment: I mean that it runs and does not encrypt the private key.

Comment: Hmm.  Strange.  We have several rigs at work running Ubuntu 12.04, in addition to my home desktop, and on all of them this fails.

Comment: So it always prompts you to enter a passphrase?

Comment: It never prompts me for a passphrase.  But the the input and output key is different, which tells me it decrypts &lt;something&gt;.  And until the key is decrypted, it cannot be used as input into another system which is expecting a decrypted key+cert.

Comment: If it doesn't prompt for a passphrase then the key is not encrypted (there's nothing to encrypt it with). The output of `openssl rsa` being different doesn't mean that there's something wrong. Please specify what problem you're actually having when using the generated key.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like the default format has changed in later versions. Earlier versions appear to produce a PKCS#1 RSAPrivateKey format as denoted by

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

and the later versions generate a PKCS#8 PrivateKeyInfo format as denoted by

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
```

when you `openssl rsa -in mykey.pem -out decryptedkey.pem` you convert from `#8` to `#1`

Comment: Perfect.  Now I understand what has happened to require us to run the extra `openssl rsa` command.  Thanks.